# BQ51050B compatibility criteria

Tags: i2c, embedded, texas-instruments, wireless-charging

I started another project where I need to charge a few devices (preferably simultaneously) wirelessly. They all have **BQ51050B** and the corresponding coil/battery.

I need to know what I should look at when deciding on what IC to choose to be compatible with the mentioned device.

On the **receiver**, I am running 3.7V 60mAH batteries and using [this](https://nl.farnell.com/wurth-elektronik/760308101104/charging-coil-6-8uh-10/dp/2965265) coil.

On the charger, I intend to control the chips using the I2C protocol.

Comment: First step is to define what you mean by "compatible with the device". Start that by reading the device's datasheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since asking this question I realized that the **qi** standard really helps you with sorting out  which active component (i.e. chip) works with which passive components (i.e. coil, battery). What is more, it can also tell you which device to pair with. For example if you have a transmitter chip, the version of **qi** helps you determine which receiver chip to use.

Read the datasheets.